# Table import failing on table with partition( ORA-00959: tablespace 'USR' does not exist)

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [oracle import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892847/oracle-import-error)

I am trying to export two tables from one DB to another :

Here is the code:

```
echo  "Exporting TMP_OA_PSTN_CMP_11035 and  table from SF-PSTN " | tee -a $sqllog
echo "Do you wish to continue (Y/N): " | tee -a $sqllog
read choice1
if [ "${choice1}" = "Y" ];
then
exp ${SF_PSTN_CONN_STRING} tables=TMP_OA_PSTN_CMP_11035 TMP_ORDER_ACTION_PSTN_11035 file=COMPLETE_OPEN_ORDERS_11035.dmp indexes=y  grants=no log=COMPLETE_OPEN_ORDERS_11035.log
else
echo "Exiting solution";
exit ;
fi

echo "Now We are importing TMP_OA_PSTN_CMP_11035 table in Router" | tee -a $sqllog

echo "Importing TMP_OA_PSTN_CMP_11035 table in SF-BIGPOND " | tee -a $sqllog
echo "Do you wish to continue (Y/N): " | tee -a $sqllog
read choice1
if [ "${choice1}" = "Y" ];
then
imp ${ROUTER_CONN_STRING} file=COMPLETE_OPEN_ORDERS_11035.dmp full=y indexes=y grants=n ignore=y log=COMPLETE_OPEN_ORDERS_11035_import.log
else
echo "Exiting solution";
exit ;
fi
```

One of the tables is sucessfully imported(TMP_ORDER_ACTION_PSTN_11035) but the other one is not.The error is :

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit 
Production
With the Partitioning and Data Mining options
Export done in US7ASCII character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
Note: grants on tables/views/sequences/roles will not be exported

About to export specified tables via Conventional Path ...
. . exporting table          TMP_OA_PSTN_CMP_11035
. . exporting partition                             P1          0 rows exported
. . exporting partition                             P2          0 rows exported
. . exporting partition                             P3          0 rows exported
. . exporting partition                             P4          1 rows exported
. . exporting partition                             P5          1 rows exported
. . exporting partition                             P6          0 rows exported
. . exporting partition                             P7          0 rows exported
. . exporting partition                             P8          0 rows exported
. . exporting partition                             P9          0 rows exported
. . exporting partition                            P10          0 rows exported
. . exporting table    TMP_ORDER_ACTION_PSTN_11035          4 rows exported
Export terminated successfully without warnings.
Now We are importing TMP_AXIS_COMPLETE_NOTIF table in Router
Importing TMP_AXIS_COMPLETE_NOTIF table in SF-BIGPOND
Do you wish to continue (Y/N):
Y

Import: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Fri Jul 20 15:20:08 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

Export file created by EXPORT:V10.02.01 via conventional path

Warning: the objects were exported by CRAMER, not by you

import done in US7ASCII character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
import server uses WE8ISO8859P1 character set (possible charset conversion)
. importing CRAMER's objects into SA
. importing CRAMER's objects into SA
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 959:
 "CREATE TABLE "TMP_OA_PSTN_CMP_11035" ("ACTION_OBJID" VARCHAR2(12), "CONTRAC"
 "T_OBJID" VARCHAR2(12), "STATUS" VARCHAR2(40), "UPDATE_DATE" DATE)  PCTFREE "
 "10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 TABLESPACE "USR" LOGGING PARTITION BY"
 " HASH ("ACTION_OBJID" )  (PARTITION "P1"  TABLESPACE "USR", PARTITION "P2" "
 " TABLESPACE "USR", PARTITION "P3"  TABLESPACE "USR", PARTITION "P4"  TABLES"
 "PACE "USR", PARTITION "P5"  TABLESPACE "USR", PARTITION "P6"  TABLESPACE "U"
 "SR", PARTITION "P7"  TABLESPACE "USR", PARTITION "P8"  TABLESPACE "USR", PA"
 "RTITION "P9"  TABLESPACE "USR", PARTITION "P10"  TABLESPACE "USR" )"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 959 encountered
ORA-00959: tablespace 'USR' does not exist
. . importing table  "TMP_ORDER_ACTION_PSTN_11035"          4 rows imported
Import terminated successfully with warnings.
```

Is it because the table TMP_OA_PSTN_CMP_11035 contains partition?Please help with this..

Comment: what was it? Looked to me like a missing tablespace. By default, an export only exports the objects in a tablespace, not the tablespace definition itself.

Comment: I created the table manually on the other DB and the import was sucessfull.Refer to the link given by alex poole.